# Выборочная компиляция *.pug в html

Tags: html, gulp, jade, pug

Как указать pug компилировать только index.pug в index.html и не компилировать файлы, указаные в include ?
Это файл index.pug:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    include parts/header.pug
  body
    include parts/footer.pug
```

Это кусок gulpfile.js, отвечающий за сборку html:

```
gulp.task('html:build', function buildHTML() {
    return gulp.src('src/tpl/**/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug({
                    pretty: true
                }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/')); // указываем gulp куда положить скомпилированные HTML файлы
});
```

Comment: Вместо `'src/tpl/**/*.pug'` напишите путь к файлу `index.pug` (`'src/tpl/index.pug'`)

Comment: Ахахахаха, восхитительно и так просто. Я аж засмеялся. Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `'src/tpl/**/*.pug'` напишите путь к файлу `index.pug`
Например, `'src/tpl/index.pug'`

Answer (score 3):

Например, можно инклуды писать начиная с подчеркивания, вроде `_header.pug`. И необходимо разделить, что отслеживается и что собирается. Ведь при изменениях инклудов нужна пересборка, но сами инклуды при этом собирать не нужно.

Скажем, в `gulp.src` можно запретить обработку файлов вида `_*.pug`, а в `watch` отслеживать изменения во всех файлах pug и запускать таск который будет пересобирать файлы.

**Например:**

```
gulp.task('html:build', function(){
    return gulp.src(['src/tpl/**/*.pug', '!src/tpl/**/_*.pug'])
           .pipe(pug())
           .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
           .pipe(// а здесь можно сделать какой-нибудь liveReload или browserSync)
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('src/tpl/**/*.pug', [html:build]);
});
```